# linker command issue With weak library

Tags: ios, tesseract

I am creating an app where I am trying to scan business card details. For this I used **TesseractOcrIos** library with **CocoaPod**. the pod is :- `'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'`  . But when i integrate that in my project it is giving linker command

> ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting
>   ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together.

Can someone please tell me what may be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Build Settings of your Project or Target and set ENABLE_BITCODE flag to NO.
Though if you need bitcode to be turned on you can try another solution: 
set ENABLE_BITCODE to YES in your Pods project, then clean and rebuild your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I missed the tessData file. So i solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines of code on on your pod file. I was having this issue for last two days. i just solved it by these lines of code. This will set `ENABLE_BITCODE` to `NO` and prevent overriding it during `cocoapod` building

```
 post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
         end
     end
 end
```